# Prevent MSVC from creating debug symbols by source code pragma?

Tags: debugging, compiler-errors, visual-c++, pragma

While compiling a large c++ program with msvc .net 2003 and with debug information, I ran into [C1067](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d8s456s8%28VS.85%29.aspx), the fatal compiler error for to big or to large debug symbols. As it is in boost, and I don't want to fiddle around with the source code, the easiest thing would be, if there is a pragma or something that could switch off the generation of debug symbols from source code side. Any idea?

Answer (score 0):

Here's a KB article suggesting compiling with /Z7 (old style debug info).  It will give an ignorable warning, and symbol info:

http://support.microsoft.com/kb/122539